# @media set all wrappers child elements

Tags: html, css

How would i set all the child elements in @media without adding all there classes.

.wrapper>* does not seem to work, not sure why.

this is a simple example:

```css
  .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .left {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  float: left;
  width: 50% !important;
}

.wrapper .right {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50% !important;
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
  .wrapper>* {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left Menu<br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Right Content<br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>


<p>Resize the browser window.</p>

<p>Make sure you reach the breakpoint at 400px when resizing this frame.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
 .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .left {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper .right {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper .left,
  .wrapper .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left Menu<br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Right Content<br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>


<p>Resize the browser window.</p>

<p>Make sure you reach the breakpoint at 400px when resizing this frame.</p>
```

Get rid of `!important` for your divs and make sure that rules in @media section have [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) no weaker than ones applied in the main section.

Besides, using universal selector (*) is not the best idea since it has no specificity value. So, `.wrapper > *` has (0,0,1,0) specificity whereas defined earlier `.wrapper .left` and `.wrapper .right` have (0,0,2,0) which is stronger than (0,0,1,0) and, thus, they win.

Although it is not that important in this case, but styles are parsed from right to left. So, having "*" on the right side may make it harder/slower for browser to parse and apply styles.

Also `!important` makes the whole styles trickier to maintain and understand so it is safe to avoid it unless it is totally necessary.